# Angular, getting watch to fire when sending same info

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a watch on a factory that will not fire when it recieves the same value, I know it's suppose to work like this but I'm wondering if there is any work around?

I have a factory that sends modal information, and the user may close the current modal and want to re open it.

The factory -

```
.factory('themeFactory', function () {
// Service logic
var x = "no";
return {
  setModal: function (modal) {

    x = modal;
  },
  getModal: function(){
      return x;
  }
};
});
```

the watch -

```
$scope.$watch(themeFactory.getModal, function (newModal) { 
  if(newModal != "no"){
    $scope.modalOpen = true;
     $scope.modalInfo = newModal;

  }else{}

});
```

So pretty straight forward in that the watch will just not fire if the user sends the same object in the setModal. Is there any reasonable way to work around this? Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, watches are triggered when there is a change in the value. Sounds like you could use events to accomplish your task:

```
//Use $rootScope to $broadcast the event
.factory('themeFactory', function ($rootScope) {
// Service logic
var x = "no";
return {
  setModal: function (modal) {

    x = modal;

    //broadcast event if not "no", your logic from $watch
    $rootScope.$broadcast(this.modalOpened, modal);
  },
  getModal: function(){
      return x;
  },

  //Defining an event name to broadcast
  modalOpened: "themeFactory.modalOpened"
};
});
```

Then in your controller (or wherever you put your watch):

```
$scope.$on(themeFactory.modalOpened, function (e, modal) {
   $scope.modalOpen = true;
   $scope.modalInfo = modal;
});
```

You don't provide enough code to show what code is called when an existing modal is reopened. I just put the $broadcast inside setModal, but you would use that anywhere you want to let your scopes know that a modal has been opened.